# Ubuntu - Your system has UEFI Secure Boot enable (while trying to upgrade my Nodejs version)

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, unix, dpkg

I've been trying to upgrade my nodejs version cause when I ran the command to install it, automatically installed v4.2.6 and i've been playing around to try to fix this and the output is always the same: UEFI secure boot is enabled, and apparently is something about the dpkg.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://askubuntu.com

Comment: broda, i need all the help i can and closing this question isn't helping me at all cause I belive that stackoverflow has a bigger community than askubuntu.

Comment: @tambre You were both right! in askubuntu I get feedback faster than here. I was just desperate, thats why I came here. Still facing issues anyways